# Navigate to the jdk folder from console on Mac system

Tags: java, android

I am new to Mac system. I want to navigate to the java jdk directory using command on Mac terminal. something similar to `cd programfiles/windows/` on windows command line.

I have tried `cd $(/usr/libexec/java_home)` to get the path but to go to the path was the challenge

> $(/usr/libexec/java_home)
>
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home system_name:$

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OSX 10.9 or newer, run this from Terminal:

`cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<jdk version>/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 0):

Type cd /Libary/Java/Javavirtualmachines/[jdk_version]

or Go to step by step
cd the enter takes you to the root directory
cd Library
ls to list the sub directory
cd java then
cd javavirtualmachines
cd jdk_version on your system